# Eclipse makes laptop unusable

Tags: arch-linux, memory, eclipse, core-dump

Currently I can't use my eclipse project. I'm using ArchLinux:

`````
                   -`
                  .o+`                 rkmax@satellite
                 `ooo/                 OS: Arch Linux 
                `+oooo:                Kernel: x86_64 Linux 3.9.9-1-ARCH
               `+oooooo:               Uptime: 1h 19m
               -+oooooo+:              Packages: 922
             `/:-:++oooo+:             Shell: bash
            `/++++/+++++++:            Resolution: 3286x1200
           `/++++++++++++++:           DE: Gnome 3.8.2
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`         WM: Not Found
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`        WM Theme: Not Found
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`       GTK2 Theme: Adwaita
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.      GTK3 Theme: Adwaita
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.     Icon Theme: Faenza-Darkest
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-     Font: Ubuntu 10
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-   CPU: Intel Core i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.533GHz
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:  RAM: 1049MB / 2808MB
 `++:.                           `-/+/  
 .`                                 `/

java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (ArchLinux build 7.u40_2.4.1-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)

Eclipse Juno 4.2 (extra/eclipse 4.2.2-1)
`````

The problem here is when I try to change anything in my project and eclipse goes to rebuild it. A process `systemd-coredum` eats all memory:

```
COMMAND                   %MEM    RSS     %CPU
systemd-coredum           54.4    1528.04 4.3
java                      9.7     272.48  69.6
chromium                  4.6     130.08  2.2
chromium                  2.1     61.12   2.9
chromium                  2.1     60.67   0.7
gnome-shell               1.7     49.16   6.4
banshee                   1.5     42.80   4.2
chromium                  1.3     37.28   0.2
chromium                  0.8     23.45   0.2
pulseaudio                0.3     10.65   2.0
```

I have `ulimit -c unlimited` in `.bashrc` file and a symlink in the coredump conf

```
$ ln -s /dev/null /etc/sysctl.d/coredump.conf
$ systemctl restart systemd-sysctl
```

But I can't solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the coredump you can disable it by limiting it's resources to 0:

```
$ ulimit -c 0
```

Check out this thread on the ArchLinux forums, looks to be an active problem as of 7/2013, https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154511.  The thread had a couple of posts that mentioned the `ln -s /dev/null ...` method as no longer working.

This wiki article titled: [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Disabling_application_crash_dumps_journaling) in the ArchLinux wiki had additional details.